# how to capture clicks event on other window that has been minimized

Tags: event-handling, hook, minimize, user32

i want to build an app that work in the background, and will capture all click events 
on the minimize button, of all opened forms / windows that actually running.  (not only in my current app)

it will be some sort of hook to add minimize handler to all of other windows.

how to setup this kind of hook ? ( please provide some code example in csharp with marsheling )

To better understand the idea : this procedure already exists in program called TrayIt that handle Ctrl+Click on the Minimize button, and send programs to system tray .

**EDIT**:

i have found that **SetWindowsHookEx** cannot set a global hook with c# due to limitation in manged code (see the msdn documentation )

but may **WinEventProc** with EVENT_OBJECT_STATECHANGE should do the work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finely i have found solution for this hook , 
this is not the best solution that i can get but it do the work

i have mixed **window_state_change** in **SetWinEventHook**

and component to track Control Key in **Gma.UserActivityMonitor**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using Gma.UserActivityMonitor;

namespace example {
    public partial class Form1 : Form {
        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public const uint WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT = 0;
        public const uint EVENT_OBJECT_STATECHANGE = 0x800A;
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr SetWinEventHook(uint eventMin, uint eventMax, IntPtr hmodWinEventProc, WinEventDelegate lpfnWinEventProc, uint idProcess, uint idThread, uint dwFlags);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool UnhookWinEvent(IntPtr hWinEventHook);

        public delegate void WinEventDelegate(IntPtr hWinEventHook, uint eventType, IntPtr hwnd, int idObject, int idChild, uint dwEventThread, uint dwmsEventTime);

        public static bool ControlDown = false;
        public static IntPtr hhook;
        static WinEventDelegate procDelegate = new WinEventDelegate(WinEventProc);

        private void load(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
            hhook = SetWinEventHook(EVENT_OBJECT_STATECHANGE, EVENT_OBJECT_STATECHANGE, IntPtr.Zero, procDelegate, 0, 0, winapi.WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT);
            HookManager.KeyDown += HookManager_KeyDown;
            HookManager.KeyUp += HookManager_KeyUp;
        }
        private void closing(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs e) {
            UnhookWinEvent(hhook);

            HookManager.KeyDown -= HookManager_KeyDown;
            HookManager.KeyUp -= HookManager_KeyUp;
        }
        private void HookManager_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.LControlKey) { ControlDown = false; }
        }
        private void HookManager_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.LControlKey) { ControlDown = true; }
        }

        static void WinEventProc(IntPtr hWinEventHook, uint eventType, IntPtr hwnd, int idObject, int idChild, uint dwEventThread, uint dwmsEventTime) {
            if (idObject == -2 && idChild == 2) {
                if (ControlDown) {

                    // HookWindow(hwnd);
                    .....
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

if you like  you can setup a simple hook with **RegisterHotKey**

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, uint fsModifiers, uint vk);
```